# numbers within apply get filled with spaces

Tags: r

I want to create a folder name based on two variables in a data frame and something is wrong here...

```
head(clustering)
  line  x  y   qerror
1  200 15 19 1.118677
2  201 11 19 1.038482
3  202  0  6 1.238026
4  203  0 18 1.321878
5  204  0 12 1.204173
6  205  5  0 1.394773
str(clustering)
'data.frame':   3406 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ line  : Factor w/ 3406 levels "1001","1003",..: 814 822 831 841 847 858 891 ...
 $ x     : num  15 11 0 0 0 5 16 8 1 0 ...
 $ y     : num  19 19 6 18 12 0 14 19 17 18 ...
 $ qerror: num  1.12 1.04 1.24 1.32 1.2 ...
```

When I try to create the folder name with the x and y columns, I do the following:

```
apply(head(clustering),1,function(x){paste0('x',x[2],'_by_y',x[3])})
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
"x15_by_y19" "x11_by_y19" "x 0_by_y 6" "x 0_by_y18" "x 0_by_y12" "x 5_by_y 0"
```

As you can see, the x and y get an additional space, if the value is smaller then 10. But when I use this without apply, it seems to work

```
paste0('x',clustering[3,2],'_by_y',clustering[3,3])
[1] "x0_by_y6"
```

Has someone an idea, why there are spaces?

Comment: I can produce it with the given col classes. Within apply, every row is casted to character. Somehow, because of the factor (?), the integer numerics with one digit are formatted with a leading space. `apply(head(clustering)[2:3],1,function(x){paste0('x',x[1],'_by_y',x[2])})` will work (the `x` vector is casted to numeric).

Comment: Whats the hype `apply` lately? Why not just some good old vectorizing? Something like `len <- seq_len(6); paste0("x", clustering[len, 2],'_by_y', clustering[len, 3])`

Comment: @lukeA, it's because of `format`.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the following lines from `apply`:

```
if (!dl) 
  stop("dim(X) must have a positive length")
if (is.object(X)) 
  X <- if (dl == 2L) 
    as.matrix(X)
else as.array(X)
```

`as.matrix` calls `format`, and `format` + `as.matrix` can sometimes do unexpected things. See the "details" section from `as.matrix`. The `format` help page also notes that *"Character strings are padded with blanks to the display width of the widest."*

Here's a demonstration showing that `format` is responsible for the behavior you have identified:

```
lapply(mydf, format)
# $line
# [1] "200" "201" "202" "203" "204" "205"
# 
# $x
# [1] "15" "11" " 0" " 0" " 0" " 5"
# 
# $y
# [1] "19" "19" " 6" "18" "12" " 0"
# 
# $qerror
# [1] "1.118677" "1.038482" "1.238026" "1.321878" "1.204173" "1.394773"
```